# Можно ли на короткий номер отправить MMS вместо SMS?

Tags: android, ios, сеть, sms, телефония

Например, для подтверждения платежа "Отправьте 1 в ответ"

Для дипломной работы (IP-сети и GSM-телефония) пишу свой клиент SMS/MMS.
Была идея взять исходник системного приложения и добавить новые возможности, но преподаватель решил, что мне стоит самому продумывать приложение, а не "вести себя как индус" или "узкоглазый", "у вас диплом не по этой теме".
Поэтому пишу с нуля.
Работаю с API Level 21, где отправка SMS и MMS теперь делаются одинаково легко, с этим проблем нет.
Но нужно изучить проблемы надежности и в пояснительной записке все описать, что и почему.

В приложении будут поддерживаться смайлики, эмоджи и прочее. При их добавлении сообщение автоматически преобразуется в MMS и затем отправляется MMS.

Но представим, что при отправке такого сообщения пользователь случайно нажал смайлик. Конечно, он его убрал и текст сообщения снова содержит только "1", но само сообщение не преобразовалось назад и отправилось как MMS.

Что произойдет?
Прокатит ли такое подтверждение?
Спишутся ли деньги за само сообщение, если, допустим, алгоритм провайдера немного сложнее, и это еще не подтверждение оплаты, а просто сообщение, которое должно оплачиваться как обычное и от обычного отличается лишь тем, что приходит на короткий номер и его там обрабатывает автоматика?
Работа этой автоматики отличается ли для SMS и MMS?

Comment: "но само сообщение не преобразовалось назад и отправилось как MMS." - а почему бы не проверять тип перед отправкой? Заодно можно и опцию сделать "Только SMS", "Только MMS", "Тип по содержимому". Пользователь не хочет отправлять MMS - уберём из сообщения всё лишнее или предупредим его о недопустимом контенте.

Comment: @Zufir все запреты я должен обосновать. в идеале - чтобы список был сервисов, кому можно отправлять MMS, кому нет